# Fortran error about EOF marker

Tags: fortran, eof

I apologize in advance as I know this question has been asked by other users and solved. However I do not seem to be able to solve it myself:

portion of the code:

```
integer variable_1 
open(522, position='rewind', form='unformatted')
  write(522) varibale_1    //This is line 110
  rewind(522)
  close(522)
```

Error:
At line 110 of file file_name (unit = 522, file = 'fort.522')
Fortran runtime error: Sequential READ or WRITE not allowed after EOF marker, possibly use REWIND or BACKSPACE

file 522 is created an another subroutine in the following way:

```
variable_1 = 0
      inquire(522, exist=lex, iostat=ios, recl=i)
      open(522,iostat=ios, form='unformatted')
      read(522, err=37, end=37) variable_1
      close(522)
      go to 38
 37   continue
 38   continue
```

I am not sure what to do, I tried placing bakcspace(522) or rewind(522) in various places and I end up with a segmentation fault or just the same error...

Note:Line 110 is the write statement.

Thank you everyone in advance.

Comment: Please see the additional information. Thank you

Comment: I did not omit anything, that really is the only portion of the code. This use to work fine with different compilers, now we are forced to use gcc. that is the issue.

Comment: That was a typo mistake, everything should be unit 522

Comment: I have inherited this code and i am stuck with it trying to fix it... any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your problem is reproducible, it happens with both (rather) current trunk and with gfortran 4.8.

What you do in the second code snippet is creating a completely empty file.  I am not sure that this is what was intended, but it happens that way.

What happens next is that the file is **not** closed on the read error.  The next open statement does pretty much nothing, it is permissible to do multiple open statements on an existing unit.  After that, hilarity ensues when you try to do I/O on a file that has an error condition.

So change your code to

```
  logical lex
  variable_1 = 0
  inquire(552, exist=lex, iostat=ios, recl=i)
  open(552,iostat=ios, form='unformatted')
  read(552, err=37, end=37) variable_1
  go to 38
37 continue
38 continue
  close(552)


  open(522, file="fort.552", form='unformatted')
  write(522) variable_1
  rewind(522)
  close(522)
end program
```

and things will be fine.

I have filed [PR 65563](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65563) and [PR 65565](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65565) about two aspects of this.

Comment: +1 for identifying the problem, but there are still a host of issues here.  Bad form to use `iostat` then not bother to check the result. Likewise the `inquire` results are not used, why not use `lex` to skip trying to open? Whats the point of inquiring `recl` on an unformatted file anyway? There is no point to `rewind` before closing. No point to closing right before `end program` for that matter. The convention of an unnamed file being named 'fort.nn' isn't standard, so either name it both places or neither.

Comment: Dear tkoenig, unfortunately this causes segmentation fault...any other options i could try?

Comment: Do you get the segmentation fault if you run the exact code I posted?

Comment: I have not tried that yet, I put this in my code and it gives me segmentation fault. I will follow your suggestion and update you in few. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried just your code and it is fine, i compiled it with gfortran and it created a file fort.522 as expected...where do I go from here?

Comment: Get rid of the whole code in the second code chunk of your code.  It does, basically, nothing.  Run the second chunk (without the file="fort.552", if you want to), this should do just fine.

Comment: I get seg fault, this is driving me nuts, maybe more complex than it seems?

Comment: Trace this as you would any segfault.  First, compile with "-O -g -fcheck=all -Wall" and fix any errors/warnings that may be important.  If that doesn't make the segfault go away, run the program under gdb and see where it occurs and what is going on there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73949/discussion-between-amani-lama-and-tkoenig).